# PHP strlen on speech marks and commas

Tags: php, string, strlen

I have the following string which is 78 chars in length:

```
PlayStation VR Available ‘April 2016’, According To VR Production Company Site
```

When I perform the PHP function `strlen` on this string it gives me a value of 90.

```
    $title_lenth = strlen($the_title);
    echo $title_lenth; // 90
```

I presume this is happening because strlen is using the html entity of the speech marks and comma which will result in the character count being 5 characters instead of 1.

How do I tell `strlen` to count punctuation as one character?

I have already tried using `mb_strlen` but it returns the same value.

Thanks

Comment: You can't change the behaviour of strlen() like that, strlen() returns the number of bytes in the string, and an html entity comprises several bytes.... what you'd need to do first is convert that entity to a character using something like [html_entity_decode()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php), and then use strlen() or mb_strlen()

Comment: Just curious - what version of PHP are you using? I'm using 5.6.19 and I get the expected result of 78 when using both `strlen` and `mb_strlen`.

Comment: in my case it gives 82 while using both strlen and mb_strlen

Comment: @mark - Thanks for the tip - however, this has reduced it to 82 - so still not the expected 78

Comment: @brandon - Im using 5.5.3, so maybe it is a PHP issue?

Comment: hi you can try this $str = "PlayStation VR Available ‘April 2016’, According To VR Production Company Site";
$str1 = str_replace(' ', '', $str);
$title_lenth = strlen($str1);
echo $title_lenth;

Comment: If those quotes really are so-called "smart quotes", then I'd expect 80 (or 82) characters rather than 78, because they're  multibyte characters

Answer (score 2):

Its looks like older PHP versions behave differently. PHP 5.5.3 was the issue.

I solved the problem with the following:

```
    $the_title =  html_entity_decode(get_the_title());
    $the_title = utf8_decode($the_title);
    $title_lenth = strlen($the_title);
```

It was the non-utf8 quotation marks that were causing the problem.

Answer (score 1):

```
$the_title = "PlayStation VR Available ‘April 2016’, According To VR Production Company Site";
$title_lenth = strlen(utf8_decode($the_title));
echo $title_lenth; // 78
exit;
```

As proposed int the comments on php.net http://php.net/manual/de/function.strlen.php#45407

Answer (score 0):

```
$str = "PlayStation VR Available ‘April 2016’, According To VR Production Company Site";
$str1 = str_replace(' ', '', $str);
$title_lenth = strlen($str1);
echo $title_lenth;
```

this will reduce string lenght to 72